# C# ASP.NET MVC : Identity seed ApplicationUser data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to seed admin user, using identity.

I have this class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surename { get; set; }
}
```

I inherited it from `IdentityUser`.

When I seed these values:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IdentityRole> builder)
{
    builder.HasData(
            new IdentityRole
            {
                Id = "1372a768-421a-440d-ac9b-3297151b4fd7",
                Name = Roles.Administrator,
                NormalizedName = Roles.Administrator.ToUpper()
            },
            new IdentityRole
            {
                Id = "a0ee1d85-8b89-4ce2-8736-8e8476747129",
                Name = Roles.Employee,
                NormalizedName = Roles.Employee.ToUpper()
            });
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
{
    var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();

    builder.HasData(
            new ApplicationUser
            {
                Id = "361e2fcb-21b1-426d-a860-c278a463356d",
                UserName = "Admin",
                NormalizedUserName = "ADMIN",
                Email = "admin@gmail.com",
                NormalizedEmail = "ADMIN@GMAIL.COM",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword(null, "Admin123!"),
                SecurityStamp = string.Empty,
                Name = "Admin",
                Surename = "Main",
            });

}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IdentityUserRole<string>> builder)
{
    builder.HasData(
            new IdentityUserRole<string>
            {
                RoleId = "1372a768-421a-440d-ac9b-3297151b4fd7",
                UserId = "361e2fcb-21b1-426d-a860-c278a463356d"
            });
}
```

Everything seems ok if I look at database, but when I try to login it fails at:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }

        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }

        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

It fails at:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

It seems like password does not match hashed password in the database.

What did I miss?

Comment: If you are sure that hashes mismatch (you are sure entered password is not misspelled) probably hash algorithms are not same when you insert and later check existing password. There is already similar question on SO [User failed to provide the correct password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63799775/asp-net-core-identity-microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-signinmanager-warning-u)

Comment: I have read it, but nothing solid, that can be done